# Onboarding screen showing once but if user is sign in not showing maintab in swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I am showing onboard view but i want to show once thats working othervise when user sing in i want to show main tab this code every time showing sign in screen. can you help me to solution.
Thank you

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
 
        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasLaunched")
        let onboardSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)
        let mainSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc: UIViewController
        if userDefaults {
            if currentUser != nil {
                let board = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let tabBar = board.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
                window?.rootViewController = tabBar
            } else {
                vc = mainSB.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SignInNav")
            }
        }
        else{
            vc = onboardSB.instantiateViewController(identifier: "OnBoardingVC")
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasLaunched")
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: are u sure current user isn’t nil?

Comment: no when user sigin current user keep cache and open directly app but if i add onboarding screen every time show signin screen